How do fixed points work in an overdamped pendulum
I am learning about stability in the context of the simple pendulum from here. I came across the following paragraph -

The first thing to notice is that the system has a number of fixed
points or steady states, which occur whenever $\dot{x}=0. $. In this
simple example, the zero-crossings are $x^{*}={...,-\pi,0,2\pi,...}$.
When the system is in one of these states, it will never leave that
state. If the initial conditions are at a fixed point, we know that
$x(\infty)$ will be at the same fixed point.

I don't understand the significance of $\dot{x}=0$. Does that mean if the system ever reaches a state where $\dot{x}=0$, it will not change? If yes, then why is the plot periodic in nature?

The linked graph shown is of $\dot{x}$ vs $x$, not of $\dot{x}$ vs $t$. So this is not indicating a periodicity in time but in space, namely $b\dot{x}=-mgl\sin x$. Note that this is a first-order differential equation, hence $\dot{x}=0$ is enough to ensure $x$ remains constant for all time.

That makes perfect sense @Semiclassical. Thanks!

The equation of motion under consideration here is that of a damped pendulum with constant torque:
$$ml^2 \ddot{\theta}+b\dot{\theta}+mgl\sin\theta=u_0$$
In the overdamped limit ($ml^2\ddot{\theta}\ll b\dot{\theta}$) with zero external torque ($u_0=0$) the equation of motion becomes
$$b\dot x=-mgl\sin x$$ where the authors have for some reason relabeled $\theta\to x$. The plot of interest is then shown:

Note, however, that this is not a plot of position as a function of time ($x$ vs $t$) but of velocity as a function of position ($\dot{x}$ vs $x$). Hence the resulting periodicity is not in time but in position, i.e., rotating the pendulum through $2\pi$ leaves the velocity unchanged. Moreover, the equation of motion is now first-order and thus $\dot{x}=\sin x=0$ is sufficient to ensure constant $x$ for all time.
